# Universal string to date conversion c#

Tags: c#, date, type-conversion

Is there a universal string to date conversion method available. I have a situation where I get a datetime value as string but the value could be in any of the valid datetime format.

How do I parse it to to DateTime object in C#?

Edit

I have a possible list of formats but that can be quite large.. I have read about DateTime.Parse(string value, string[] format, culture, style) method where I can pass multiple formats in the format parameter and one of the possible format would be matched.. So how much performance impact would this approach have? –

Comment: From where I see it, what you request is impossible... let's say I give you this input : `01/02/03 11:22:33`, how would you guess the original format ? If you can't, how would a computer do ? If your input is in several different formats, you will need to input the format together with the data if you want an accurate result when parsing.

Comment: I have a possible list of formats but that can be quite large.. I have read about DateTime.Parse(string value, string[] format, culture, style) method where I can pass multiple formats in the format parameter and one of the possible format would be matched.. So how much performance impact would this approach have?

Comment: If your input is coming from different regions, your best bet is to use that region's culture to parse the data.

Comment: You can read many docs, the fact is that you can never guess with a 100% certitude what the original format is without "asking the client" , except for very specific cases (e.g : `25/12/67 22:35:00` is obviously Xmas , most probably in 1967 , at 10:35 PM)

Answer (score 3):

Quick answer: universal: No.

Because there are written date formats that are ambiguous. Eg. to me today is "08/04/14", but in a historical context to the west of the Atlantic that could be the 4<sup>th</sup> August in an earlier century.<sup>1</sup>

If you have a subset of formats to process then [`DataTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22) has an overload that takes an array of formats to try in turn.

Any method that you do not pass a date format to will use the current locale settings to start the parsing: which is likely to lead to invalid parses because you don't know the input format.

The best solution is to use ISO format (`yyyy-MM-dd`) the next best is to get the precise rules from whomever is specifying the system.

EDIT: Additional. While the best and next best may not be possible, the various `DataTime` parse, try-parse and -exact methods have overloads that accept an `IFormatProvider` (which `CultureInfo` implements) that would allow you to be explicit about the source of the data.

In terms of performance (from updated question): in an earlier version of the framework I looked at `DateTime.TryParseExact` in some detail, and I seem to recall it simply tried each format in turn finishing as soon as it got a successful parse. Thus if the most common format is first in the array its performance will be little different to the single format overload. But (1) if you need this functionality then you need it, whatever the overhead; (2) it seems unlikely your application's performance will be much affected by this (compared to, say, the cost of reading the data into and writing it out of the application).

---

<sup>1</sup> Strictly speaking this is not true, I've worked too often with the, IMHO, horrible US format to know to write today as "2014-04-08".